# Printing a Tree With Indents. Swift

Tags: swift, data-structures, tree

Implementing a Tree data structure using swift:

```
class Node {

    var value: String
    var children: [Node] = []
    weak var parent: Node?

    init(_ value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func add(_ child: Node){
        children.append(child)
        child.parent = self
    }

    func printTree() {
        var text = self.value
        if !self.children.isEmpty {
            text += "\n  " + self.children.map{$0.printTree()}.joined(separator: ", ")
        }
        print(text)
    }

}
```

My goal is to see something like this:

```
A1
    B2
    C3
        G6
    K0
        H7
            L8
        L9
```

I know there should be some smart way to insert indents, but I also struggle with 'map'. Compiler gives me "ambiguous reference to member 'map'".

Comment: Instead of (or in addition to) a `printTree()` method you can implement the `description` method of the `CustomStringConvertible`, which then allows you to print a tree with `print(node)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think vacawama's answer is quite *smart*, but if you want to practice recursive call including `map`s, you can write something like this:

```
class Node {
    //...

    func treeLines() -> [String] {
        return [self.value] + self.children.flatMap{$0.treeLines()}.map{"    "+$0}
    }
    func printTree() {
        let text = treeLines().joined(separator: "\n")
        print(text)
    }
}
```

To test:

```
let a1 = Node("A1")
let b2 = Node("B2")
let c3 = Node("C3")
let g6 = Node("G6")
let k0 = Node("K0")
let h7 = Node("H7")
let l8 = Node("L8")
let l9 = Node("L9")
a1.add(b2)
a1.add(c3)
a1.add(k0)
c3.add(g6)
k0.add(h7)
k0.add(l9)
h7.add(l8)
a1.printTree()
```

Output:

```
A1
    B2
    C3
        G6
    K0
        H7
            L8
        L9
```

Some points:

- Your `printTree()` is a void function, so using it in `map` produces an Array of empty tuples, which cannot be `joined`.

  (In Swift, void functions can be considered as returning empty tuple. And Swift generates **ambiguous reference to member** when an appropriate overload cannot be found.)

  You may need an intermediate function the result of which can represent a partial tree structure.
- Indentation needs to be added to each line, so the intermediate result should easily be separated into lines.

Comment: Appreciate you pointing out that i can't use Void func in "map".

Comment: Still don't understand the usage of `flatMap{$0.treeLines()}`... I thought $0 in flatMap is the array itself, not its members?

Comment: @Evgeny, when the closure returns an Array for each iteration, `flatMap` concatenates all Arrays into a single flat Array. At each iteration, `$0` becomes a child in `self.children`, so `$0.treeLines()` generates an Array of `String` and `flatMap` concatenates all such Arrays into a single Array of `String`. If you need more illustrated explanations, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make it pretty, you could do this:

```
extension Node
{
   func treeLines(_ nodeIndent:String="", _ childIndent:String="") -> [String]
   {
      return [ nodeIndent + value ]
           + children.enumerated().map{ ($0 < children.count-1, $1) }
             .flatMap{ $0 ? $1.treeLines("┣╸","┃ ") : $1.treeLines("┗╸","  ") }
             .map{ childIndent + $0 } 
   }

   func printTree()
   { print(treeLines().joined(separator:"\n")) }
}

a1.printTree()

// A1
// ┣╸B2
// ┣╸C3
// ┃ ┗╸G6
// ┗╸K0
//   ┣╸H7
//   ┃ ┗╸L8
//   ┗╸L9
```

You could also generalize it into a print function for any tree structure that will let you choose what to print for each node:

```
func printTree<T>(_ node:T, _ nodeInfo:@escaping (T)->(String,[T]) ) 
{
  func lines(_ aNode:T, _ nodeIndent:String="", _ childIndent:String="") -> [String]
  {
    let (label,children) = nodeInfo(aNode)
    return [ nodeIndent + label]
         + children.enumerated().map{ ($0 < children.count-1, $1) }
           .flatMap{ $0 ? lines($1,"┣╸","┃ ") :lines($1,"┗╸","  ") }
           .map{ childIndent + $0 }
  }
  print( lines(node).joined(separator:"\n") )
}

// print a root node providing a capture to obtain the node's label
// and its array of children

printTree(a1){ ($0.value,$0.children) }

// works for any tree structure.  for example, views :

printTree(view){( "\(type(of:$0)) \($0.frame)", $0.subviews )}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
func printTree(_ indent: String = "") {

    print(indent + self.value)

    for child in children {
        child.printTree(indent + "    ")
    }
}
```